# How to write click event to image inside png in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have png image with a hole inside it so that image behind it is seen thru this. What i need is, i want to write click event to this inside image. Is it possible?

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/madhu72kumar/VFmAY/1/)**

```
//code
 $('#ant).click(function()
    {
        alert("hi");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create an Image Map.
Check out http://www.image-maps.com for a relatively easy way to generate one, or the W3Schools page on the <map> tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda difficult to achieve this by using jQuery (the image on the top always takes the click event), what I suggest you is to take a look at the `<map>` tag:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: i can't use map tag because this is for responsive and map tag can't be used for responsive know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the top image is still there, even if it is see through. You can try to get the location clicked in the top image doing something like this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VFmAY/2/)

```
 $('#rainbow').click(function (e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var left = e.clientX - offset.left;
    var top = e.clientY - offset.top;
     if (left > 95 && left < 300) {
         if (top > 95 && top < 220) {
             alert("hi");
         }
     }
 });
```

The above is actually really close, but as the image opening isn't square it's not perfect. You could log the `left` and `top` to play around with it and figure out exactly what you want to count and add more logic if you want something more exact.

Answer (score 0):

in jquery you can place the click event on both images and the top image will `trigger` the bottom images click event

```
$("#topImage").click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#bottomImage").trigger("click"); 
});

$("#bottomImage").click(function(e) { 
    alert("bottom image beep"); 
});
```

so clicking the top image will trigger the bottom images `onclick` handler

Comment: and how would the bottom image ever get a click event if there is an image on top of it?

Comment: the `trigger` method does just that and triggers the event specified on that queryed node

Comment: Ah, missed that part. But this would have the same affect as just putting the alert directly in the topImage. (he only wants it to work if the click is within the see-through part of the topImage)

Comment: thats true dont see how else youd want todo it tho.

Answer (score 0):

Put a picture as the background in the first DIV, DIV second position in the center of the hole, the third DIV use to write an alert.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#ant).click(function()
        {
            $('#message).html("Hi. This is event inside hole...");
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="background-image">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="message"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="ant">Click and write</button>
```

Of course, everything you need to fine combing with CSS...

Answer (score 0):

In addition for all the things that said here here, `<area>` tag can help you.
Although coordinates is old way to write effective code, they have the ability to aim specific points on image by typing `x1,y1,x2,y2` for `shape=rect`, `x,y,radius` for `shape="circle"`. 
You also have `shape="poly"` for polygon, which written by `x1,y1,x2,y2,..,xn,yn`. 
I suggest that you could try this way and choose what is your favorite and of course the most effective for you. 
**[W3SCHOOLS AREA TAG EXPLAIN](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_area_coords.asp)**